# Typing 'paral' into Spotlight suggests 'Pages' instead of 'Parallels Desktop' - how to fix?

Tags: macos, spotlight

If I type any of these in Spotlight (Yosemite):
par
para
parall
parallel
etc

Parallels Desktop is suggested as the program to launch - which is what I want.

However - if I type 'paral' - what you would think was a good short bet to load the app - it suggests 'Pages.

I endup typing 'paral' a lot as it used to work.

I found nothing on Google.

This makes no sense. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If Parallels is in the suggestions below, scroll down and select it. Do it a couple of times and it will become the top result eventually. App launching is adaptive.

Comment: Only needed to do it once thanks! I guess I must have somehow typed 'paral' then clicked Pages in the past one time to cause this.

Answer (score 5):

Rebuilding your index should fix this. You can do it typing this command at the terminal:

```
sudo mdutil -i on /Volumes/Macintosh_HD
```

Replace `Macintosh_HD` with your hard drive name.

Comment: sudo mdutil -i on '/Volumes/Macintosh HD' < says 'Indexing enabled. Zero effect (it was also super fast don't think it did anything.

Comment: I have not updated the name of my hard disk - so the path above should be right?

Comment: Also tried this - same as above: sudo mdutil -E /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/

Comment: Do you have enough space on that disk? What is the output of `sudo mdutil -s /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD`?

Comment: 30Gb free. Output as it says above 'Indexing enabled'